# Libwbxml compiling on Win32 environment

Tags: winapi, wbxml

I've downloaded libwbxml source package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwbxml/files/libwbxml/0.11.0/ and followed instructions in the INSTALL file, trying to compile it for Windows environment. However, everytime I build the solution (I'm using VS 2005), I get several error messages like this:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wbxml_config.h': No such file or directory

I've searched throughout the web and could not find a definitive solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, building on Windows with Visual studio 98 will cause no error.
You may try to build another variant, wbxml2-0.9.2.tar, from sourceforce.net, it only causes error at test phase but the library and 2 tools can be built fine.